# Spring boot test failing to get data populated at start of test

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a sql file which looks like this:

```sql
--Testdata
INSERT into cms_patch.configuration_main(document_key, config)
values('TEST/PhoenixTest', '{"b" : "c"}');
```

I am trying to run a test and want to seed this data to the table before that test, but the data is getting rolled back before the test happens.

Test class:

```java
@Sql({"/sql/cms_dao_data.sql"})
public class CmsDaoImplTest extends AbstractPhoenixDao {

    @Autowired
    private CmsDao cmsDao;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeMethod() {
        this.cmsDao = new CmsDaoImpl();
    }


    @Test
    @Sql("/sql/cms_dao_data.sql")
    public void containsDocumentKey() {

        Boolean result = cmsDao.containsDocumentKey("TEST/PhoenixTest");
        assertTrue(result);

    }
}
```

abstract class:

```java
@Transactional
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application-test.properties"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RepositoryContext.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class AbstractPhoenixDao extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    public AbstractPhoenixDao() {
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to know why the data is getting rolled back before the test happens.
the data is getting created because if I keep 2 values in insert with same primary key the sql run at start gives an error.
we are using postgres.

Comment: I'm confused with your set-up. Remove `@Transactional`, remove the method annotated with `@BeforeMethod` and remove one of the two `@Sql` annotations.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I have removed it, but the state is same. the data is getting populated but getting rolled back before the test

Comment: As a test, what happens if you add `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` ?

Comment: The code looks like
`@Sql("/sql/cms_dao_data.sql")
public class CmsDaoImplTest extends AbstractPhoenixDao {

    @Autowired
    private CmsDao cmsDao;

    public CmsDaoImplTest() {
        this.cmsDao = new CmsDaoImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void containsDocumentKey() {
      // from service layer
        Boolean result = cmsDao.containsDocumentKey("TEST/PhoenixTest");
        assertTrue(result);
    }
}`

Comment: But why add `@Autowired` to cmsDao when you also do `this.cmsDao = new CmsDaoImpl();`? Just autowire and remove the CmsDaoImplTest constructor

Comment: @NicoVanBelle There is no change with this annotation

Comment: I have removed the constructor, That was a mistake